# Comparing characters of a list of arrays

Tags: c#

This is the exercise that I have to deal with:

> You are given a word and a list of words. Your task is to check
> whether all the words from the list are anagrams of the word. Input
> Read from the standard input
>
> On the first line, find W - the word to check against; On the second
> line, find N - the number of words in the list of words WORDS; On the
> next N lines, the words from WORDS; Output Print to the standard
> output
>
> For each word from WORDS print either: "Yes", if the word is an
> anagram of W; "No", if the word is NOT an anagram of W;

And this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        string word1 = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] mainWord = word1.ToLower().ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(mainWord);
        int numberOfWords = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<Array> anagramWords = new List<Array>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
        {
            string wordForList = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] wordCharacters = wordForList.ToLower().ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(wordCharacters);
            anagramWords.Add(wordCharacters);
        }

        foreach(object word in anagramWords)
        {
            if (word == mainWord)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

For some reason, the answer that I get is always No.

Comment: `foreach(object word in anagramWords)` don't use `object` here - instead use the real type of what `anagramWords` contains, namely `char[]` - `object` gives you the default comparer when you do `==` and that compares reference addresses, not contents.

Comment: Need to compare each character the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (word == mainWord)
```

doesn't compare the content of the *word* array with the content of the *mainWord* array.
Array variables are references types, or, in other words, they just contain the *reference* to the memory area where the elements of the array are really stored.
So if you compare the two arrays in that way you are comparing
two values (two references) that point to the memory area where the respective elements are stored. Of course these values are different because, even if the arrays contain the same characters, the elements are stored in different memory areas.

To solve your problem a different approach is needed.
Something like this should work

```
static void Main()
{

    string word1 = Console.ReadLine();
    IEnumerable<char>mainWord = word1.ToLower().OrderBy(w => w);
    
    int numberOfWords = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    List<IEnumerable<char>> anagramWords = new List<IEnumerable<char>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
    {
        string wordForList = Console.ReadLine();
        IEnumerable<char> wordCharacters = wordForList.ToLower().OrderBy(fl => fl);
        anagramWords.Add(wordCharacters);
    }

    foreach (var word in anagramWords)
    {
        // Here we are asking to compare the full set of elements
        // with each other and we find if they contain the same data.
        if (word.SequenceEqual(mainWord))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A string is already an array, no need to call `.ToCharArray()`. May as well drop the `.ToLower()` as well and use a string comparer in `SequenceEquals`.